# Pre-answer command-line output

Tags: unix, continuous-integration, command-line-interface

I've got problem with my CI server. When it does the build there is an command line answer that I need to answer. And it stops the build. I don't remember how to pre-answer such questions?

I'm running `npm install yeoman -g`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's specific to the app, but I've seen `-y` before used to confirm prompts.

Comment: Is it just -y after the command. Because I don't think that worked

Answer (score 0):

If the answer is "yes", you can try:

```
yes | npm install yeoman -g
```

`yes` takes an argument if you need a different response.